# How to set expiry in new Couchbase PHP SDK

Tags: php, couchbase

I am having trouble finding good tutorials and documentation on the newest couchbase PHP sdk. I am trying to do a bucket upsert and want to set the document to expire in 24 hours. I know the third parameter if an array of options and I tried an associative array like 
$bucket->upsert($key, $value, array("Expiry" => 10))

to see if this would result in the document being removed in 10 minutes. but that didn't seem to work. The doc is inserted but it stays around every 24 hours later.

How do I make this happen? Can someone show me some sample code. This is the only thing holding me back on my current project and I would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example of setting a document to expire in 24 hours:

```
$cluster = new CouchbaseCluster();
$bucket = $cluster->openBucket();
$result = $bucket->upsert('Mission-possible', ['Secret-message' => 'This doc will self destruct in 24hours'], array('expiry' => 60*60*24 ));
```

There are a few things to be aware of when it comes to expiry. If the expiry value is 2592000 or below it is treated as a off set by the cluster in seconds. If the value is above 2592000 it is treated as an absolute epoch timestamp.

The [developer guide](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/doc-expiration.html) explains expiry in more details.